# i3-wm switching from dual do single screen - unplugging hdmi

Tags: 16.04, hdmi, window-manager, xps, i3-wm

Switching from a 2 monitor set up (external screen), to a single monitor (internal laptop screen), i3 still "places" workspaces on the disconnected screen.
I tried:

```
i3-msg restart
```

but it doesn't mitigate the problem. The screen was connected via HDMI. Running ubuntu 16.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
xrandr --query
```

to confirm which port you want to change. Assuming it's `HDMI1`:

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --off
```

might do the trick, setting:

```
bindsym $mod+m         exec xrandr --output HDMI1 --off
```

for easier usage.

Comment: one-liner `xrandr --output $( xrandr | grep 'HDMI.* connected' | head -n1 | awk '{ print $1 }' ) --off`